# Hashmark in Scala type declaration -- What does `P#Backend#Database` mean?

Tags: scala, slick

In the Slick library we find this declaration:

```
/** A configuration for a Database plus a matching Profile. */
trait DatabaseConfig[P <: BasicProfile] {
  /** Get the configured Database. It is instantiated lazily when this method is called for the
    * first time, and must be closed after use. */
  def db: P#Backend#Database
}
```

What does `P#Backend#Database` mean? What does `#` do? Is it a standard Scala construct or something from a library?

Comment: [Path dependent types](https://www.artima.com/pins1ed/abstract-members.html#20.7). `Database` is a type defined in `Backend`, and `Backend` is a type defined in `P`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `#` symbol in a type declaration is similar to a `.` in normal code: it refers to a *type* defined inside a type. Here is a simplified example:

```scala
trait Profile {
  type Database
}

trait Config[P <: Profile] {
  def db: P#Database
}

case class MyProfile() extends Profile {
  type Database = String
}

case object MyConfig extends Config[MyProfile] {
  def db = "mydatabase" // has the type MyProfile#Database, that is, String
}
```

If we change the type of `db` to something else:

```scala
case object MyConfig extends Config[MyProfile] {
  def db = 123
}
```

there is an error that explains what the type means:

```
type mismatch;
 found   : Int(123)
 required: MyProfile#Database
    (which expands to)  String
```